# Named Exports in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Can we have named export in Lightning Web Component?

In ES6 module there are two ways of exporting module:
Default Export
Named Export
I am able to find deault export in lwc

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {}

But I have not seen named export in LWC so want to know if they are used in lwc?

According to ES6
There can be several named exports in a ES6 module. A module can export selected components using the syntax given below −

```
export component1
export component2
...
...
export componentN
```

Answer (score 1):

The main class for a component with a UI must be the default export. However, you are free to export as many symbols as you like, which can be useful for [service components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/lightning-web-components-service-components.html), which are those that do not have an html file. The named export rules work per the ES6 specification:

```
export { symbol1, symbol2 as symbol3, ... }
```

However, you must use the `{ symbol }` notation. The exact form you specified in your question is not supported.

In fact, that's not valid ES6. The valid types of [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) are:

```
// Exporting individual features
export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, const
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const
export function functionName(){...}
export class ClassName {...}

// Export list
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };

// Renaming exports
export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };

// Exporting destructured assignments with renaming
export const { name1, name2: bar } = o;

// Default exports
export default expression;
export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
export { name1 as default, … };

// Aggregating modules
export * from …; // does not set the default export
export * as name1 from …; // Draft ECMAScript® 2O21
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { default } from …;
```